# Bing Search API supports multiple request?

Tags: jmeter, search-engine, bing-api

im trying to do an load test on my page that uses Bing seach API for user queries in a search box, i wanna know who many searching users can handle my web, to do that i configure a Jmeter test, but when i run it appears to fail at 90% of searches, ¿there is any limitation on this api on multiple users that search at same time?

Answer (score 1):

Bing does have API limits, the free Tier is 5,000.  You should be able to see your limits at

https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44

To validate this, I create a load test to hit my 5,000 per month limit to see re-create the rate limit condition.

The error output and copy of the JMX is available at [Load Test Bing](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11621).  The test launched on 5 servers, each running 100 users, looping 11 times.

This first test run shows that you can quickly hit the ‘per minute’ which you can see in your error responses

`Code(503) Message(The number of requests per minute for the subscription has reached the maximum threshold that is allowed. Please try again after….`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply, was very helpful for me, but i still have one doubt ¿ in the payment tier still exist this maximum number of requests per minute?

Comment: As it relates to the Bing API, I do not know.  Perhaps send support ticket to them.  However, for other paid APIs I use they do have per second and per minute rate limits to curb abuse.   I wrote up a blog post about my test case for [JMeter and Bing](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/02/jmeter-load-testing-against-public-apis-bing-use-case/).